# difference between "be free" and "get free"?

Tags: grammar, american-english, speech

What is the difference between the two? And if I want to meet a friend what would I say "I'll be free soon " or "I'll get free soon "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two mean almost the same thing, in that you're expressing the fact that you'll be free soon.

However, "get" means "obtain", so "I'll get free" means "I'll obtain freedom". This implies that you aren't currently free, but you will be after some amount of time.

On the other hand "I'll be free" doesn't imply that you *aren't* free now. The addition of the "soon" makes that contextually obvious, but by itself "I'll be free" doesn't technically mean the same as "I'll get free".

Comment: There is also the point that 'get free' is rarely used for trivial situations. I'll get free from this quicksand somehow / I'll get free from these shackles / *I'll get free from this hairdressing appointment. 'Be free' is _sometimes_ used with trivial situations: I'll be free in an hour / *I'll be free from this hairdressing appointment.

Answer (score 1):

"I'll get free" usually implies that some action will have to be taken in order to achieve freedom. So a slave might say "I'll get free by the end of the month", or someone in a meeting will say "I'll get free in time to come to the other meeting", both implying they will have to do something to achieve it.

"I'll be free" implies that this is something that would happen without them having to do anything to achieve it.

Comment: I was going to say that context is important.  Bondage vs. schedule.  But, I guess the notion of the schedule is a metaphor for bondage.